# "Roboshield account corrupted" -- what?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, robocraft

After signing in with Steam Account, I attempted to join a Deathmatch and twice in a row right after the screen displaying the players joining the match, I was kicked with the message

> Roboshield account corrupted

Now I have an "Abandon Battle Penalty" which occurred due to something that wasn't even my fault.

I don't know if this is relevant, but my wait time is also consistently much longer than the displayed average wait time.

How can I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @Nzall MacOS Sierra 10.12.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [forum post](https://robocraftgame.com/forums/topic/roboshield-account-corrupted/) discussing this error, and two users suggests that uninstalling the game and reinstalling it should do the trick:

> So, I found that when this “corruption” thing kicks in, if I uninstall the game and re-install, it works again. However. I’ve had to only re-install twice (when I had to leave a match mid-way due to an emergency...the “corruption” kicked in again).
>
> Saw this on the support page. I uninstalled and reinstalled and it worked.

One of these users also suggested that you uninstall it and run a virus scan on your computer afterwards, and reinstall.

On the [second page](https://robocraftgame.com/forums/topic/roboshield-account-corrupted/page/2/) of the forum, a user stated that restarting the game did the trick for a little bit, until the error eventually came back.  Seeing that this is an Early Access game on Steam, errors like this should be expected I would say.

Lastly you can [submit a request](https://freejam.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) to the development team, though don't expect any immediate results.

Comment: Hah, it's an early access game that's been actively developed on for several years. You'd think they'd have ironed out major bugs like this by now. Thank you for finding that forum thread though.